# JSF HTML SelectOneMenu scroll

Tags: google-chrome, scrollbar, selectonemenu

I´m using h:selectOneMenu

It works fine, but on **Chrome** I cant get the scroll bar to work properly.
If I rotate the mousewheel, it works fine, but if I click on the bar and try to move up/down, it doesn´t work.

On IE it works both ways.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read that it is a bug on chrome.
One cant scroll down a combobox field on chrome (32.0.1700.76 m) by clicking on the scroll bar. one has to use the mousewheel or arrows!!